# What is the difference between a filling date and reporting date

Tags: stocks

What is the difference in EDGAR report compny between a filling date and reporting date

Comment: @keshlam I think it's a fair question, although it might fall into a gray area. A lot of investors like to look at 8-Ks and other SEC filings.

Answer (score 3):

- The **filing date** is when the report was submitted
- The **reporting date** is the as-of date referenced in the report (usually the quarter or fiscal year end date).

But your data source might be using a different naming convention so it's best to double check.